# Dynamically fill div with same ID using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, history.js

I am using History.js to dynamically fill the body of my html pages in order to prevent entire page refreshes. However, I am having trouble getting data and filling a div if they are the same ID. All of my pages are structured:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="container">
        ...
```

Here is my current jQuery/history.js

```
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {
    var State = History.getState();
    $.get(State.url, function(data) {
        $('#content').fadeTo(600, 0, function() {
            $('#content').html($(data).find('#container').html()).delay(200).fadeTo(600, 1);
        });
    });
});
```

I want to be able get data from 'content' and also fill the 'content' div, but when I change the variable in find() to 'content', it will return nothing.

Comment: Ideally all your ids should be unique otherwise the selectors don't work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

Was able to create a work around by using `$(data).find('#container').parent().html()`

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use something like this? :

```
$('#content').fadeTo(600, 0, function() {
        $(this).children('#container').html(data).delay(200).fadeTo(600, 1);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try `$(data).find('div[id=container]').html()` instead of `$(data).find('#container').html()`.

And you are trying to replace `content` div's html with `container` div's html. You will lose the `container` div

Comment: I want to get the html from 'content' not container. However, when I change `$(data).find('#container').html()` to `$(data).find('#content').html()` it isn't returning anything.

Comment: I do NOT want to replace `content` div's html with `container` div's html. I simply want to replace the `content` div's html of one page with that of another.